# Multiple anchor tag click on one jQuery event is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor

I have multiple anchor tag in a page. I want to click all the tag from jQuery to open each link in a new tab. But it is working only for the first element.

My attempt is below:

```
    $('.tbl a').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    window.open(url, '_blank');

})
```

Note: if I set background color in each it works well. Then why not new Tab?

Comment: The `target` (the 2nd) argument is the same, it refers to the same window, hence a new tab is not opened. Use a different value for each window.

Comment: so you could maybe use `.each(function( index )` and concatonate index onto the target, to make new names for the tabs

Comment: @Teemu any idea how to bind value to window

Comment: ?? Stender has a good suggestion above.

Comment: Nothing wrong with code, it is the pop-up blocker blocking so many new tabs.

Comment: @VivekK. you are right, the pop up issue. Stender code works but need to disable popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion from the comments would look something like this :

Won't work here, because the sandoxed frame does not allow popups, but you get the idea.

```js
$('.opener').on('click',function(){
  $('ul a').each(function (index) {
      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      window.open(url, '_blank'+index);

  })
})
```

```css
.opener{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#FFF;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>open new tabs</h1>

<p>An unordered list:</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.coffe.com">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.tea.com">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.milk.com">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="opener">test open </p>
```

Comment: It works when pop up blocking is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer in the comments,

```
$('.tbl a').each(function () {
  $(this).on("click", function(e){
    window.open(e.target.href, '_blank');
  })
})
```

Comment: your solution is not working surprisingly no error also. Thanks for your attempt